# Op Amp gain modification from kenwood krf-7060d

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, gain

[image]

Hi, I have an kenwood krf-7060d, which has an subwoofer line out that is very very "quiet". The top part of the schematic has the final opamp (sw out) before the acutal output. Can someone tell me what is the best way to increase the gain(modify r227?) and what are the workabouts of the resistors and capacitors connected to the op amp? Thank you!

Mentions: the opamp works at +/- 12V, the gnd line is where r223 and r224 come together. The whole service manual can be found here https://www.manualslib.com/download/953472/Kenwood-Krf-V7060d.html

Comment: Transistor's answer is correct but that stage already has a gain of 60 which is ... pretty high. Check for voltages on R437 (should be about 0) or faulty Q337 first in case the muting circuit is operating when it shouldn't. Also, what power amp is this feeding into?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I`ll check to see if q337 conducts when it shouldn't. In the specs it says PRE OUT (SUBWOOFER) 2.5 V / 1 kΩ (should have about 40mV at the opamp input). From the user settings, the volume of the subwoofer output is set to +10db. From the pre-out it is fed into an active subwoofer, which is also tested onto another receiver, so the problem it's not from the subwoofer. Does r237 could be removed entirely from the circuit?

Comment: R237 ,1k, does not get attenuated much by R223, 47k but any dry ecaps may attenuate alot, yet unlikely on this pre-amp.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Close-up reveals a non-inverting amplifier.*

The gain of a non-inverting amplifier is given by \$ 1 + \frac {R_f}{R_i} \$. The simplest fix is to raise the value of R<sub>f</sub>.

Answer (score 1):

Changing R227 is not a good idea because you will alter the rolloff caused by C225. Reducing R225 will give more gain without a noticable change in response because C223 is larger than needed. The low frequency corner is currently 4Hz; dropping R225 by half would double the gain and make the corner 8 Hz. It is also much easier to splice a new 820 ohm resistor in parallel with the existing one.